# Error in mapping binary 16 bit data from Django model to Django Admin

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, uuid

I have a 16 bit binary field in MySql database. I mapped the field to a Django model using the following approach:

```
class BookingFareDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.BinaryField(primary_key=True)
```

In this approach When I am tried to display the same on Django Admin, I ran into the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: ordinal not in range(128)

Then I tried to change the type of the field:

```
class BookingFareDetails(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, primary_key=True)
```

And ran into the following error:

> raise ValueError('badly formed hexadecimal UUID string') ValueError:
>   badly formed hexadecimal UUID string

Any help on how to display the binary field to Django admin would be great.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full error traceback.

Comment: 16 bit is just an int. Were you perhaps thinking of 16 bytes?